# Download file from a remote server with Rest API using JAX RS

Tags: java, rest, download

I need to download file from a remote server using JAX RS and this is my code:

```
package rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@Path("/restwb")
public class FileResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{companyName}/{Type}/{cl}/{fname}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("fname") String fileName, @PathParam("companyName") String CompName,
            @PathParam("Type") String Type, @PathParam("cl") String cl) throws FileNotFoundException {


        Response response = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResource(CompName + "/" + Type + "/" + cl + "/" + fileName + ".png").getFile());
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(inputStream);
            rb.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
            response = rb.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return response;

    }

}
```

My Question is how can i save an image in my remote server and then to download it.I test it in localhost it work correctly but if i test it in remote server i can 't to save and download.

> 2019-03-11 13:20:48,385 INFO 
>   [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Initiating Jersey application,
>   version 'Jersey: 1.19.2 08/25/2016 12:00 AM' 2019-03-11 13:20:49,300
>   INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   71) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /RestWS 2019-03-11
>   13:20:49,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request
>   Threads -- 7) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "RestWS.war" (runtime-name :
>   "RestWS.war") 2019-03-11 13:24:54,763 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /content/RestWS.war/WEB-INF/classes/Intercable/IOS/Iphone/a_red.png
>   (No such file or directory) 2019-03-11 13:24:54,764 ERROR [stderr]
>   (default task-8)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,764 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) 2019-03-11
>   13:24:54,764 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138) 2019-03-11
>   13:24:54,764 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   rest.FileResource.downloadFile(FileResource.java:43) 2019-03-11
>   13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2019-03-11
>   13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 2019-03-11
>   13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,765 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,768 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,771 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,771 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,771 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   2019-03-11 13:24:54,774 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Hello and welcom to SO. Please edit your question to add the exception stackTrace as text.

Comment: i think you are referring the relative path , you need to refer actual file path

Comment: Hello, how can i refer to actual path i want to download from remote server.

Comment: <build>
 <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/Design</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
       
       </resources>
   
  </build>
</project>